# Bundle ID does not appear in iTunes Connect

Tags: app-store-connect

- created App ID - DONE
- created development provision profile - DONE
- when creating App in iTunes Connect I would hope to select appropriate Bundle ID, but that is not listed

Comment: There's some more suggestions what to try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335495/bundle-id-is-not-showing-in-itunesconnect-bundle-id).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is happening since around 14 hours so far, it's a server issue and it's not the first time to occur.

Comment: Where should the bundle id normally appear in the current version of iTunes Connect?

Comment: The question was about the creation of an app in itunesconnect so in that step the bundle id appears under the app name field and the app default language selection.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread, but hopefully this will help users in the future.

If the Bundle ID is not appearing inside AppStore Connect (formerly iTunes Connect) as an option when creating a new app, it is possible that the app has previously been created and then subsequently removed.  That stops the Bundle ID from being used again. Information about this can be seen at https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev28d17ed35.

Next:

- When on the My Apps screen, towards the top right hand corner, change All Status to Removed Apps.
- If the app in question exists, click into it and go to App Information on the left hand side.
- Scroll to the bottom of the screen and click Restore App.

According to Apple, if the ID has already been used, it cannot be selected again, so in this scenario, the options are to either restore the app and work with that listing or create a new Bundle ID.

Hope that helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, however it's the first that shows up on google, since this issue can still happen.

Miraculously, clearing the Safari cache solved this problem for me, after I waited for almost a day.

Comment: Deleting cookies, CTRL+F5 or restarting the browser did not help in my case.